# Longlisting Files & Directories

Tags: command-line, files, directory, ls

I would need to know if there's a way to differentiate files & directories .

**Note :** Without using longlisting

Comment: you mean you dont want to use `ls -F` ? You want to do it with someother command ?

Comment: Yes , exactly the wat I need

Comment: @AgentCool  your answer was helpful for me . That is what I required .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
ls -d /home/$USER/Documents/*/
```

it will list all dirs in Documents. The last "/" makes it "directories" only.

Comment: Yeah , Tried this today . It's helpful , thanks